# Not able to upload file using Angular JS $http Post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

My Form data is:

```
 var fd = new FormData();
 //Take the first selected file
 fd.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0], "abc");
```

My API request is:

```
var config = {
            withCredentials : false,
            transformRequest : angular.identity,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        }
return $http.post(url, fd, config)
```

At the backend I'm still not getting any object in params.

Let me know why I'm not getting any form data at backend.

Comment: any errors? did you try to debug with browser developer tools?

Comment: @melgart No, I am not getting any errors.

Comment: how/where is 'url' defined?

Comment: Not much to go on here. Can you post the backend logic?